# Bluemix toolchain export & import

Tags: ibm-cloud, toolchain, devops-services

If I have created a bluemix toolchain through UI, how can I export that. I see there's an option to create a toolchain from a template described in yml files. But how can I get these yml files for an existing toolchain created using UI. Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate more because I have worked with Bluemix and toolchain as well

Comment: @Abdullah - Jeet wants to see if there is a way to create a toolchain using an existing toolchain (not the pre-defined template). If the toolchain information is available in YAML it can be changed using a text editor (instead of the Toolchain UI) and can be stored in a version control system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In it's current form and shape, there isn't a import-export option for the toolchains.

The existing toolchain templates have a [repository](https://github.com/open-toolchain) where the file representation is stored (YAML, JSON and others).

Clone a toolchain from this github repository to create your own toolchain and make the relevant changes.

For the pipelines that you created using the UI, you can see the YAML contents by adding "/yaml" to the URL.

For example,
If your pipeline URL is:

https://console.bluemix.net/devops/pipelines/pipelineIDENTIFIER?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south

then the YAML can be seen by using the URL below:

https://console.bluemix.net/devops/pipelines/pipelineIDENTIFIER**/yaml**?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south

Amend the repo with this YAML file (for the pipeline) and you now have a repo that can be used to create your toolchain.

In summary, not a straight-forward way to import-export however it can be done with some effort.

Comment: This technique no longer works - appending `/yaml` gives a 404 Not Found.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier, Thanks for sharing the info that this technique does not work any longer. This was not a documented option (then or now) . This hack used to work for more than  a year and possibly does not work any further.  I tried this morning and receive an "Internal error". I did not get a 404. I should have stated that this was a hack in my response last year as this was never stated in the documents.