# The Delivery Pipeline service is being initialized. This might take a minute

Tags: ibm-cloud, toolchain, continuous-delivery, devops-services

I need the 'deploy to ibm cloud' button to clone and deploy 3 Git repos. I had a look around and per [Bluemix toolchain export & import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532786/bluemix-toolchain-export-import) I figured what could work well is to modify https://github.com/open-toolchain/microservices-toolchain-hosted.  And it is giving me a lovely UI which creates 3 correctly cloned repos and 3 pipelines.  But I cannot get in to any of the pipelines - they all say (forever):

> The Delivery Pipeline service is being initialized. This might take a minute...

One of the pipeline.yml I have used before with the 'deploy to cloud' button, but just for one repo, and that worked.

In the console I see:

> de87fd0d-f482-492a-8e3b-618a9ea2dfa2?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://pipeline-ui-service.ng.bluemix.net/devops/pipelines/socket.io/?pipelineId=de87fd0d-f482-492a-8e3b-618a9ea2dfa2&sessionId=f0145a6d-924d-4922-a464-60109321bba5&time=1513850425418&EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

I'm struggling to debug this.  I can't find any logs or clues to say what is wrong.  Am I going about this the right way?  Are there any logs/way to debug this?  Or even any docs, all I can find is about setting it up in the UI.  Which is fine, that works.  But I want it just like that open toolchain which simplifies it for my customers.

EDIT: I narrowed it down to the removal of saucelabs.  I removed its yml file and all references to it from the toolchain.yml and pipeline*yml files.  And now the pipelines won't initialize, even when I use the default microservices repos.  Here is the commit: https://github.com/MaeveOReilly/toolchain-fun/commit/6a9e1f49deca4b1f2932789fb60fbf39339f1d42#diff-08ef8388c233ad3eb0b293470baa5d23

And here is a faulty pipeline:
https://console.bluemix.net/devops/pipelines/52a0dcd6-38a8-4452-9e48-03c895484f1e?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I also needed to remove references to the 'test' service in the toolchain.yml.  I removed the service, which was where I found the saucelabs stuff, but failed to remove refs to it.

```
 ui-build:
service_id: pipeline
parameters:
  services:
    - ui-repo
    - test
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are docs about DevOps Open Toolchain and debugging here:

https://github.com/open-toolchain/sdk/wiki

Let me know if that's enough, or if you would like some more assistance.

---

If you have a sample repo available, I can help debug it or get in contact with the DevOps team to help fix it.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  I looked through them but I'm still not figuring out where I'm gone wrong.  I am working from here: https://github.com/MaeveOReilly/toolchain-fun.   And here is one of the faulty pipelines: https://console.bluemix.net/devops/pipelines/2e896cd7-f3d0-467d-a14f-36484cf012ef?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south

Comment: Okay, by taking a quick look at your repo, I'm pretty certain the error is that your configuration yml files are invalid. I tried just using the basic microservices starter they have on the DevOps GitHub [here](https://github.com/open-toolchain/microservices-toolchain-hosted) and switched the toolchain git urls to the same ones in your codebase (after I clicked **Create Toolchain**), and the Deploy Pipeline correctly initialized (although two repos failed on the *Build Stage* and the other on the *Deploy Stage*).

Comment: Thanks for looking Joe.  I'm going to start again but this time more iteratively so I have a clue when it goes wrong - the zero errors/logs here isn't working out for me ;-).

Comment: Yes, I suggest trying to integrate one repo at a time, iteratively. That will make it easier to keep track of if the changes you're making are valid and you can verify that the Stages are working. The DevOps service does log errors according to the docs [here](https://github.com/open-toolchain/sdk/wiki/Debug-Toolchain-Template-Issues) but I wasn't seeing anything for your repo.

Comment: It fell apart very quickly - as soon as I remove saucelabs.  And I still cannot figure out why but I guess I better ask that as a new Q.

Comment: Changed my mind and did an edit instead - don't think it warrants a new Q.  it's wrecking my head at this stage.

Comment: Let me forward this on to someone on the DevOps team. They might be on vacation, but they may be able to take a look at this when they get a chance.

Comment: Thanks for your help Joe.  I finally figured it out and put in the answer.